# How to determine sound choice of 'scale' when performing forward selection with gam::step.gam?

Tags: r, gam

I want to use `gam::step.gam` with `direction = forward`.  The help doc indicates that the default value of `scale` may not be a sound choice in this case.  How do I determine a sound choice for `scale`?

Comment: This isn't really a programming question. If you have questions about statistical modeling, you should ask over at [stats.se] where statistical questions are on topic.

Comment: Got it.  I've posted this question on Cross Validated here: http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/254341/138121